# Comment a key/value pair with Ruamel.Yaml

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I need to comment a key/value pair entirely using ruamel.yaml. Something like:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

inp = """\
# example
foo: bar
"""

yaml = YAML()
code = yaml.load(inp)
code['foo'].comment() # or whatever, can't seem to find a way to do this with existing api

yaml.dump(code, sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
# foo: bar
```

Of course for multiline yaml key/value pairs it would need to comment the entire value:

```
foo:
 - item1
 - item2
```

to

```
# foo:
#  - item1
#  - item2
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do your example using the existing routines for adding comments. In `ruamel.yaml` these comments are attached to either a dict (i.e. `CommentedMap`) or a list (`CommentedSeq`) and your end-result has neither.

You would need to dump the loaded `code` and, using the `transform` parameter of `.dump()` to add the start-of-line `#`  sequence.

(Although you don't need that, it is possible to do that for some subpart of a data structure loaded from a YAML document. You would need to dump the key-value pair as a new dict (again with the transform parameter) and insert/update the result on the preceding key as comment, prepending a newline.)